# How to preload a div combobox in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have code as follows:

```
$("#item_select").change(function() 
{ 
    var params = $("#item_select option:selected").val();
    $.post('/account/ar_form.php', {idata: params},  function(data){
        $("#message_display" ).html(data);
    });
});
```

This is a dropdown that uses /account/ar_form.php to display html in the div correctly.

But it only displays on the change event.  I'd like it to preload the data.  When I use a load event, it will display the html, but on change, it displays it twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#item_select").change(function(){ 
    var params = $("#item_select option:selected").val();
    $.post('/account/ar_form.php', {idata: params},  function(data){
        $("#message_display" ).html(data);
    });
}).triggerHandler("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends a bit... what does your ar_form.php return with blank params?

You could do a hackish way (at fear of being downvoted) by calling

`$("#item_select").change();`

Comment: ar_form basically displays 
<TR >
              <TD width="40%"><? print $strFieldName; ?></TD>
              <TD width="60%"><input type="text" name="<? print $ar_row['field']; ?>" id="<? print $ar_row['field']; ?>" value="<? print $ar_row['value']; ?>" ></TD>
            </TR>

Comment: with blank params it will display the table elements based on a default value...so if nothing is posted to ar_form, it will display it based on a default value....

Comment: @Jon, is that going to be a problem ?

Comment: i don't see how this will work. Don't i need to "load" the data initially?

Comment: Well if you call the change event, if should request your ar_form.php file with (supposedly) idata: '', which may do what you're requiring.

Comment: is there a way to check to see if a div elememt has html content?